# How to create a Batch File to copy the latest file based on time stamped filenames

Tags: batch-file

I have a dir of CSV files which have a date time stamp in their file-name. I need to copy the file with the most recent date time in the name.

I am a newbie when it comes to batch scripting this is what I have so far, as you can see it copies a single file but does not loop through all file-names and only copying the most recent dated.
**Thanks for the help.**

```
SET sourceDir=\\source\path
SET targetDir=\\target\path

copy "%sourceDir%\examplefile_20160111_010003.csv" "%targetDir%\newname.csv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no command that is able to do this. You have to use a little trick:

`dir` is able to sort alphabetically (that's exactly, what you want here) with `/on` parameter. `/b` gives you the filename only, /a-d excludes folders:

```
dir /a-d /on /b
```

You want the last one. Get it with a `for` loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /on /b "%sourceDir%\examplefile_*.csv"') do set latest=%%a
```

Then you can `copy "%sourceDir%\%latest%" "%targetDir%\newname.csv"`